# WPF - EF + Unit of Work + MVVM Ligth Toolkit howto register dependencies

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, mvvm, toolkit

I have a question, I am not sure if this is possible. I am creating a project in visual studio 2017 (WPF / c#), with several layers.

- Model (Net Standard 2.0)
- Domain (Net Standard 2.0) - (EF + Repository +    UOW)
- BusinessServices    (Net Standard 2.0)
- WPF  (Net FrameWork 4.7)   (MVVM Ligth Toolkit)

I need to register in IOC of MVVM light toolkit the UoW, but I don´t know how.

In My BusinessService I have this file ExcelServices.cs

```
namespace BusinessServices
{
    public class ExcelServices : IExcelServices
    {

        private IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
        private readonly ILogger<ExcelServices> _logger;

        public ExcelServices(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork,
            ILogger<ExcelServices> logger)
        {
            _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public IEnumerable<Objects> GetAllObjects()
        {
            var objects = _unitOfWork.ObjectsRepository.GetAll();
            _logger.LogInformation("Inside BusinessServices->GetAllObjects");
            return objects;
        }

        public int SaveChanges()
        {
            return _unitOfWork.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

in My WPF I have this in my ViewModelLocator.cs

```
defaultContainer.Register<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();
defaultContainer.Register<LoginViewModel>(false);
```

In the loginViewModel.cs

```
    private IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;


    public LoginViewModel(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Objects> GetAllObjects()
    {
        var objects = _unitOfWork.ObjectsRepository.GetAll();
        return objects;
    }
```

This not work.Can you advise me want can I do. I am lost in my thought

Thanks,

Best regards.

Comment: Can you describe what isn't working, is any exception thrown? You haven't shown the XAML, are you resolving the view model in the view XAML, as you normally do in MVVM Light?

Comment: Hello FantasticFiasco,I solved like this         private readonly IExcelServices _excelServices;

        public LoginViewModel(IExcelServices excelServices)
        {
            _excelServices = excelServices;
   var objects = _excelServices.GetAllObjects();
   .....
        }